# what is the dual space of this vector space $W=\{(x_1,\dots,x_n)|x_1+\dots+x_n = 0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces

I have this question in my linear algebra homework, but I can't wrap my head around it. We're supposed to prove that
$$
W^* = \{f|f(x_1,\dots,x_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_ix_i,\sum_{i=1}^na_i=0\}
$$
But I can't reason to myself why for example the function $f(x_1,\dots,x_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ is *not* in $W^*$. Is it not a linear function that assigns a scaler to every vector in $W$?

Comment: The function $f$ that you define is the zero functional on $W$.

Comment: Regarded as a function on $W$, $f(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i$ is the zero map, so it is in $W^*$.

Comment: But it's clearly not in the provided set, as $a_1+\dots+a_n=n\neq 0$. Is the set wrong? if yes then what is the correct dual space

Comment: It is because $f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=0x_1+0x_2+0x_3=x_1+x_2+x_3$ where $(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in W$.

Comment: what about g(x,y,z) = x. even still I have no idea how to prove it either and I would really appreciate some help in that regard

Comment: Thanks I think I finally got it

Comment: Restricted to $W$ we have that 
$$f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\sum^{n}_{j=1}a_jx_j=\sum^{n}_{j=1}a_jx_j-\frac1n A\sum^n_{j=1}x_j=\sum^n_{j=1}(a_j-\frac1nA)x_j
$$
for all $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in W$; hence
$f(x)=\sum^n_{j=1}b_jx_j$ for all $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in W$, where $b_j=a_j-\frac1nA$.